# How could I set fields in ng-admin dynamically based on an ajax responsponse?

Tags: ng-admin

I've tried and succeded to set the fields dynamically in ng-admin by making a OPTIONS request to my api and using that json. So far so good. But when I tried to refactor this to put it in a class, the browser start realizing I was making a SYNCHRONOUS request in the main thread and prohibited. (Some how when I don't use a class or call another function It doesn't detects it). 
Any way, My question is if ng-admin has a proper way to configure the fields based on an ajax response.

Thanks for the help